# Method with annotation @PostConstruct (javax) doesn't call

Tags: java, dependency-injection, postconstruct

Is it possible to call a specific initialization method right after calling the constructor using annotations from javax?

I put the `@Inject` annotation `(javax.inject.Inject)` over the field that I want to initialize in the method with the `@PostConstruct` annotation `(javax.annotation.PostConstruct)` right after the constructor is called, but this init method is not called and NPE crashes.

```
public class ClassChild extends ClassParent{

   @Inject
   private SomeService someService;


   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){

      someService = new SomeService(getSomeValues())  // getSomeValues() a method from parent
   }
```

Am I using these annotations correctly? What is the problem? How to call the init() method right after calling the ClassChild constructor? I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: It's all wrong. You're trying to use `@PostConstruct` to initialize `someService`, which should be injected.

Comment: Why are you initializing something (`SomeService` in this case) which is actually meant to be injected/autowired? Also, a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` is generally used to consume the injected bean or do whatever after this bean is ready.

Comment: @Isank I have never used these annotations, so i've done this wrong. i just need to initialize "someService" right after creating an instance of ClassChild  (without explicit call of init()).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ClassChild` is not a managed object (e.g. a `@Component` in Spring), so neither `@Inject` nor `@PostConstruct` will work. You're not supposed to call the constructor, you need to have the framework initialize `ClassChild`, after which the framework will also call the `@PostConstruct` method.

Answer (score 2):

Note that both @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations are part of Java EE. And since Java EE has been deprecated in Java 9 and removed in Java 11 we have to add an additional dependency to use these annotations:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[enter link description here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy)